# how to insert many lines in one single record mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I have a text file containing quote and author.

My problem is that the quote sometimes expands more than one line.

So it is not as easy as comma separated or tab in order to insert records into mysql.

I tried and every line ends up in a column, instead of every quote in a column inside the table.

How can I circumvent this?

Also quotes sometimes include "," commands and "." periods.

So my delimiter should be \t tabs.

But again my main problem is the fact that one quote expands multiple lines.

Any suggestions welcome

Comment: Please show us some code what you have tried? And from where are you inserting? Text file, CSV file, Excel file?

Comment: You can replace this kind of characters temporarily e.g replace comma , with | and after inserting/update in db you can change I with , again. You can also temporarily change ' with `